# How would one test uploading a document to a webapp?

Tags: web-applications, tdd

I am working on customizing a web application and it involves some files being uploaded, then moved around, then based on my actions, the app should do some actions. Specifically, I'm customizing Alfresco Community version (latest SVN build, that'd be 4.0+).

I want to do some tests for this functionality (not to break it in the future).

What test framework should best suit my purpose and what would be (generalized) steps for creating and running automated tests for such behavior?

You get a bonus if the test app can also check e-mail to see if my app sent it :)

[edit] Adding an example here:
I want to create a test that will do the following:
- log in to the application
- navigate to a certain part of the app
- click a button (made out of pure javascript, no markup)
- this button opens up an upload form
- use the form to select two example files from my computer
- click on "submit"
- verify that the file is uploaded

Comment: Alfresco is built in Java and is using Spring Framework. So (almost) any framework or library that works in Java could be used here.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some specific answers.